# How can I wire a ceiling fan with two 14/2 cables?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I have a single 14/2 supply line going into a switch box with two single pole switches. From there, two 14/2 lines go to a ceiling junction box with a fan that has a blue, black, and white wire. This fan also has a remote control. I'd like to have one switch control the fan blades and another control the fan lights. I can't find a diagram for it but the one I posted is basically what I am working with except the Power Supply is not at the fan, its at the switch box so I can't actually use this diagram:

[image]

I imagine I could use the black wire from one of the 14/2 lines to power the fan, and the black wire from the other 14/2 line to power the light, and not use the second line's white wire. In effect making this more like a 14/3 to the ceiling junction. I doubt that is safe or code (correct if wrong).

Rewiring isn't really an option so if I can't setup the switched fan and switched light separately, it looks like I could just disuse one of the 14/2 lines and use a single switch....but that would be fan + light on/off and having to use the remote, which isn't ideal.

Any options here? Maybe a special kind of switch or something else I'm nothing thinking of?

There is also a second downstream junction box with another fan if that's relevant but it inherits the wiring from the first junction box.

Comment: You say the diagram you posted an image of isn't correct, but you don't tell us what the correct diagram _is_.  Are the wires from the two switches really two independent sets of wires?  Only one of which has the power coming into it?  I doubt it, but you haven't told us what it actually is.  Find or make a picture of how the wiring goes.

Comment: I'm presuming one fixture neutral in my answer, since that's what's shown in the diagram.

Comment: Is getting some sort of smart-switch or fan-speed controller in not an option either?

Answer (score 0):

*(Please pardon the wiggly lines. Trackballs are wonderful for many things, but drawing smoothly is not one of them.)*

If you can pull new wiring, the obvious solution would be using four-conductor (including ground) cable rather than three-conductor:
[image: Two switches, one hot/alternate-hot/neutral/ground output cable, explicitly grounded switches]

... I'm not sure how else one could solve it, other than using pullchain switches in the fixture or a remote of some flavor.

Comment: The first wiring arrangement's a Code vio -- 300.3(B)/310.10(H) prohibit parallel neutrals like that, and you can't simply abandon one of the neutral wires either as then you'd have issues with current not returning on the same cable it came in on

Comment: Zapped, then. Better solutions welcome...

Comment: The model of fan is Aerodyne with LED 52inch: https://www.hunterfan.com/products/ceiling-fans-aerodyne-with-led-light-52-inch-smart-1001161

Comment: The first wiring arrangement by Keshlam is exactly the way it is currently wired and it doesn't work, which is why I came asking. You have to have both switches on for the light AND fan to work or just one switch for the fan to work, but independent light switching doesn't work. I guess the easiest thing to do would be to abandon one of the switches and cap that line; cap the blue light power line, and use the remaining 14/2 cable with the fan power line and fan neutral. At least, that is what the instructions say is a viable design for a single switch setup.

Comment: If it didn't work, I'm not sure I buy your assertion that it was wired that way.

Comment: @Jimmy, Instead of having everyone guess how the fan is currently wired, post a pic or a diagram of what is there now.

Comment: @Jimmy  If it does not work right with using that diagram, Then either you goofed up the wiring or the fan is defective.  Pictures of the fan wiring and the switch will be helpful.

Comment: Hold on. The instructions say to just cap the blue line to have one switch control both light and fan, or to run the fan without the light? If it's the former, I'm very confused and want to see those instructions.

Comment: Today I removed the second 14/2 line going to the fan junction. So now there is just the 14/2 supply going to the switch box and a 14/2 going from there to the fan junction. At the fan, the blue line is capped and the fan/light can be controlled by remote control. This is per the instructions here: https://image.hunterfan.com/3963-01.pdf